# Making alternating tensors out of arbitrary ones

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

The following excerpt is taken from *Differential Topology* by Guillemin and Pollack on page 155. [image]

But if $$\text{Alt}(T) = \frac{1}{p!}\sum_{\pi \in S_p}(-1)^{\pi}T^{\pi}$$

and $T^{\pi} = (-1)^{\pi}T$ and $(-1)^{\pi}$ is $+1$ or $-1$ depending on whether $\pi$ is even or odd, then for fixed $\pi$ don't we have $(-1)^{\pi}T^{\pi} = (-1)^{\pi}(-1)^{\pi}T = T$? Then $\text{Alt}(T)$ would simplify to
$$\text{Alt}(T) = \frac{1}{p!}\sum_{\pi \in S_p}T$$

This clearly seems like an error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $T$ used in the construction of an alternating tensor is arbitrary. It says "$T$ is any $p$-tensor". Whereas the equality $T^{\pi} = (-1)^{\pi}T$ is satisfied exactly when $T$ is alternating, i.e., an arbitrary $p$-tensor doesn't have to satisfy the above equality, hence you can't use the equality $T^{\pi} = (-1)^{\pi}T$ to simplify the RHS of the definition of $\text{Alt}(T)$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $T^\pi = (-1)^\pi T$ holds iff $T$ is alternating, and you used that equation. Hence what you've computed is $\operatorname{Alt}(T)$ for an alternating tensor $T$. Your last equation $\operatorname{Alt}(T) = \frac{1}{p!} \sum_{\pi \in S_p} T$ simplifies to $\operatorname{Alt}(T) = T$ since there are $p!$ copies of $T$ in the sum. This just says that the $\operatorname{Alt}$ operator restricted to the alternating tensors is the identity, which should be pleasing!

If $T$ is not alternating, then $T^\pi \neq (-1)^\pi T$, and the rest of your computation for $\operatorname{Alt}(T)$ is incorrect.